# iText PDF writer Java strange issue

Tags: java, itext

I am facing a strange issue while working with iText 5.1.3 PDF library with java. my code is working fine when i use the main method to run the code and it generated the PDF, but when i am using the same function in the web application where i need to download that PDF it shows an exception on the frontend

```
HTTP Status 500 - Dispatch[/Invoice] to method funcName returned an exception
```

while it does not print any exception on the console. 
Here is my code, can anyone please review my code and explain what is the issue with this code.

```
import com.ilex.invoice.reporting.common.IlexReportPDFConstants;
import com.ilex.report.pdf.helper.PDFUtils;
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.html.WebColors;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class SimpleTable {

    public static final String DEST = "results/tables/simple_table.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException, Exception {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new SimpleTable().createPdf(DEST);
        new SimpleTable().generateInvPDF();
    }

    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException, Exception {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(),
                IlexReportPDFConstants.PAGE_LEFT_MARGIN, IlexReportPDFConstants.PAGE_TOP_MARGIN, IlexReportPDFConstants.PAGE_RIGHT_MARGIN,
                IlexReportPDFConstants.PAGE_BOTTOM_MARGIN);

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        document.open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(76);
        table = populateHeader(table);
        for (int aw = 0; aw < 150 * 76; aw++) {
            table.addCell(getNormalCell("Some Text Here", 1.5f));
        }
        table.setTotalWidth(800f);
        table.setLockedWidth(true);

        document.add(table);
        document.close();
    }

    public static PdfPCell getNormalCell(String string, float size)
            throws DocumentException, IOException {
        if (string != null && "".equals(string)) {
            return new PdfPCell();
        }
        Font f = new Font();
        f.setColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
        f.setSize(size);
        f.setStyle("normal");
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(string, f));
        cell.setNoWrap(false);
        cell.setBorderWidth(0.1f);
        return cell;
    }

    public static PdfPCell getHeaderCell(String string, float size)
            throws DocumentException, IOException {

        Font f = new Font();
        f.setSize(size);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(string, f));
        cell.setNoWrap(false);
        BaseColor myColor = WebColors.getRGBColor("#D3D3D3");
        cell.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
        cell.setBorderWidth(0.1f);
        return cell;
    }

    PdfPTable populateHeader(PdfPTable table) throws Exception {
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Invoice #", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Approved Date", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("PO#", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Partner", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Category", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Comcast Vendor ID", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Comcast Site Code", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Authorized", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Invoiced", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Approved", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Customer", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Project", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Job", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Site", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Job Complete", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("First onsite", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Last offsite", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("PO Complete", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("PM", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Owner", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Partner / Invoice", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Dup Inv check", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Dup PO Number", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Layout code", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Source Name", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Invoice Type", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("operating Unit", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Vendor Number", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Vendor Site Code", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Invoice Num", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Invoice Date", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Currency Code", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Invoice Amount", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Invoice H Desc", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Pay Group", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Invoice Line Type", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Invoice Line Number", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Inv L Description", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Inv Line Amount", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Tax Code", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Concatenated Distr Acct", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("Source Sys Ref", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Attribute3", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Attribute4", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Attribute5", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Attribute6", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Attribut7", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Attribute8", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Attribute9", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Attribut10", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Attribute11", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Attribute12", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Attribute13", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Attribute14", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Attribute15", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("L Attribute1", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("L Attribute2", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("L Attribute3", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("L Attribute4", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("L Attribute5", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("L Attribute6", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("L Attribute7", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("L Attribute8", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("L Attribute9", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("L Attribute10", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("L Attribute11", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("L Attribute12", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("L Attribute13", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("L Attribute14", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("L Attribute15", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Attr Category", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("L Attr Category", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Terms Date", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Terms Name", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Attribute1", 1.8f));
        table.addCell(getHeaderCell("H Legal Entity Name", 1.8f));

        return table;
    }

    /*
     * public static void main(String[] args) { try { float indentationLeft = 20f; float indentationLeftTemp = 20f; List prtLst = new List(List.UNORDERED);
     * prtLst.setListSymbol("\u2022"); prtLst.add("P1"); prtLst.setListSymbol("+"); prtLst.add("P2"); prtLst.setListSymbol("\u2022"); List prevList = prtLst; for (int i =
     * 0; i < 500; i++) { List chldLst2 = new List(List.UNORDERED); chldLst2.setIndentationLeft(indentationLeft); indentationLeftTemp += 20f;
     * chldLst2.setListSymbol("\u2022"); chldLst2.add("YY" + i); prevList.add(chldLst2); prevList = chldLst2; } prtLst.add("P3");
     *
     * Document d = null; if (indentationLeftTemp > 400f) { Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(indentationLeftTemp + 200f, indentationLeftTemp + 200f); d = new
     * Document(pageSize); } else { d = new Document(); } PdfWriter.getInstance(d, new FileOutputStream("D:/test.pdf")); d.open(); d.add(prtLst); d.close(); } catch
     * (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } }
     *
     */
    private byte[] generateInvPDF() {
        File tempFile = PDFUtils.getTempFile();
        Document document = null;
        OutputStream pdfOut = null;
        InputStream pdfIn = null;
        try {
            //IlexReportPDFConstants.PAGE_SIZE
            document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(),
                    IlexReportPDFConstants.PAGE_LEFT_MARGIN, IlexReportPDFConstants.PAGE_TOP_MARGIN, IlexReportPDFConstants.PAGE_RIGHT_MARGIN,
                    IlexReportPDFConstants.PAGE_BOTTOM_MARGIN);

            pdfOut = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, pdfOut);

            document.open();
            document.add(new Chunk(""));
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(76);
            table = populateHeader(table);
            for (int aw = 0; aw < 150 * 76; aw++) {
                table.addCell(getNormalCell("Some Text Here", 1.5f));
            }
            table.setTotalWidth(800f);
            table.setLockedWidth(true);

//            PdfAction action = PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(1, new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT, 0, 10000, 1), writer);
//            writer.setOpenAction(action);
            writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.FitWindow | PdfWriter.CenterWindow);
            document.add(table);
            document.close();

            pdfIn = new FileInputStream(tempFile);

            return IOUtils.toByteArray(pdfIn);
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                try {
                    document.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            IOUtils.closeQuietly(pdfOut);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(pdfIn);

            try {
                if (tempFile.exists()) {
                    tempFile.delete();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Issue occurs when it tries to add cell to table i-e `table.addCell` 
When it reached to addCell line it does not say anything, no exception thrown and control transferred to finally block of `generateInvPDF()`
thanks in advance.

Comment: That error is usually caused by missing jars. Are you sure you've put the right jars in the right place on the web server?

Comment: While you're checking jars, maybe replace the 5.1.3 jars with 5.5.13.

Comment: *"while it does not print any exception on the console"* - Probably you'll find the exception in a log? Web applications usually are run as a service where console output does not make much sense...

Comment: im locally debugging the code :(

Comment: More interesting than the standalone code would be the webapp code. It seems that you have some error within your webapplication (and not the PDF code). What application server are you using? Did you check the server.log / console? If your are debugging within your server locally does the debugger gets triggered when you call your method? If so you should be able to see an exception, too...